# Check that a function template is invocable

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, c++20, callable

I have a function template as in the following minimal snippet. I want to test if it is callable before making the call:

```
#include <concepts>

void f(auto a) {}
// void f(int a) {} // This is ok

static_assert(std::invocable<decltype(f), int>);
```

But it does not compile with error

```
error: 'decltype' cannot resolve address of overloaded function
```

---

Alternatively,

```
void f(auto a) {}

template <auto F> concept callable = requires { {F(27)}; };

static_assert(callable<f>);
```

gives error

```
error: unable to deduce 'auto' from 'f'
```

---

Is this a limitation of C++20 language? Is there any way to force an instantiation of `f<int>`? Are there alternatives to make the check compile without changes to `f`?

Comment: ¿Why don't you just use `f<int>` to instantiate?

Comment: Because the concept is in a header file and does not know about `int` or a class that behaves like `int`.

Comment: @Arjonais: He's asking why you don't invoke it as `callable<f<int>>`. `f` is a template; `f<int>` is a function. Or rather, `is_invokable<decltype(f<int>), int>`.

Comment: ¿What do you mean "does not know about int"? You are using `int` as a second parameter to `std::invocable` right there.

Answer (score 1):

A function template can only perform template argument deduction if you *call it*. So if you're not calling it, the only things you can do with a function template name is give it the template parameters you want (thus resolving into an actual function).

Comment: Wait, am I not calling f(27) in the requires clause of the concept callable?

Comment: @Arjonais: You can call whatever you want in the `requires` expression, but C++ won't get that far because `auto F` is a *value*, not a function template.

Comment: @Arjonais: whereas `f<int>` passes your concept, `f<char>` passes it also, and `f<std::string>` doesn't. You might wrap your template function in class instead `struct F { void operator()(auto e) { f(e); } };`, then `F` is callable.